# how to inject @ObservedObject and @EnvironmentObject dependencies to a view to allow mocking

Tags: swift, swiftui, dependency-injection

In UIKit MVVM it is common to inject view model protocol in the view so that the concrete view model can be easily swapped( i.e for a mock for testing purposes).

I'm trying to replicate the same mechanism in SwiftUI, and I managed to get something very similar making the view generic over the view model protocol. The view model is also declared as @ObservedObject in this case. Then in a preview I can decide to use the view model mock and everything seems to work fine.

Then if I try to replicate this mechanism for a view ( MyView2) that, in this case needs an @EnvironmentObject viewModel, I would need to change every initialiser of MyView2 to indicate the current concrete type of view model in angle brackets. So this is clearly not a solution of my problem because I am not injecting a different  viewModel in a single place as I want.

I haven't seen many article about this problem and I appreciate any suggestion to solve it.

````
import SwiftUI

protocol ViewModel: ObservableObject {
  var count: Int { get }
    func increase()
}

class MyViewModel: ViewModel {
    @Published var count: Int = 0
    func increase() {
        count += 1
    }
}

class MockViewModel: ViewModel {
    @Published var count: Int = 0
    func increase() {
        count += 2
    }
}

struct MyView<VM: ViewModel>: View {
  @ObservedObject var viewModel: VM
  var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 20) {
      Text("Count = \(viewModel.count)")
      Button(action: {
        self.viewModel.increase()
      }) {
          Text("Increase")
      }
    }
  }
}

struct MyView2<VM: ViewModel>: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: VM
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Text("Count = \(viewModel.count)")
            Button(action: {
                self.viewModel.increase()
            }) {
                Text("Increase")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var viewModel = MyViewModel() // I can also use MockViewModel()
    static var previews: some View {
        MyView(viewModel: viewModel)
    }
}

struct MyView2_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var viewModel: MyViewModel = MyViewModel() // I can also use MockViewModel()
    static var previews: some View {
        MyView2<MyViewModel>() // <--- Here I need to change every instance of MyView2
            .environmentObject(viewModel)
    }
}



```
````

Comment: `EnvironmentObject` is only injected after view constructor call. Unfortunately, you will need to provide the generic parameter

Comment: @davidev, I can see that. that's why I'am asking for an alternative solution that brings back the advantages of the Dependency Inversion Principle that we have learned to use and love and that was easily implemented in UIKit and that looks difficult to implement it in SwiftUI.

Comment: See the three solutions mentioned here then: https://forums.swift.org/t/using-mock-protocol-as-environmentobject/64199

Comment: @davidev thanks for the links. the discussion on the swift forum confirms my fears. It's sad to see that the the iOS platform is evolving in a way that makes developers have to give up using basic proven SOLID principles like Dependency Inversion Principle or the ability to polymorphycally decide what concrete dependency to use at run time . Some people like Malhal are also advocating towards the idea of not separating the UI from the presentation logic which seems another loss to me.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need the view model object in SwiftUI because that is the job of the View struct and state, so it's simply

```
struct MyView: View {
    @State var count = 0
```

And you're done.

To pass it down to a child `View` use let for read access or `@Binding var` for read/write. Group related vars into a custom struct if you like and provide logic in a mutating func. Use computed properties to convert from rich model types to simple types to pass values into child Views that are easily previewable.

For a dependency like a controller object see EnvironmentKey, eg how the built-in authorizationController is implemented.

Requested example:

```
struct Content {
    var text1 = ""
    var text2 = ""

    var isValid: Bool {
       text1.count > 0 & text2.count > 0
    }

    mutating func reset(){
        text1 = ""
        text2 = ""
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var content = Content()

    var body: some View {
        TextField($content.text1)
        TextField($content.text2)
        Button {

        }.enabled(content.isValid)
    }
}
```

Test:

```
import XCTest

final class TestTests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUpWithError() throws {
        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
    }

    override func tearDownWithError() throws {
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
    }

    func testExample() async throws {
        let content = Content()
        XCTAssertGreaterThanOrEqual(content.isValid, false)

        content.text1 = "a"
        XCTAssertGreaterThanOrEqual(content.isValid, false)

        content.text2 = "b"

        XCTAssertGreaterThanOrEqual(content.isValid, true)
    }

    func testPerformanceExample() throws {
        // This is an example of a performance test case.
        measure {
            // Put the code you want to measure the time of here.
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean I don't need the view model? I've clearly stated the reason of why I need the view model: being able to separate the view from the view model throw a protocol interface I would be able to change the concrete implementation of the view model like using MockViewModel for a preview or for unit tests.

Comment: In SwiftUI the view is already separate and automatically generated from your View data structs it doesn't need unit tests that's already been done by Apple. You can make generic View data structs to work with mock controllers/managers/clients like this: 14:23 - Testing your app with mocks https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10171/

Comment: Malhal, as you can see in my case I don't have any apiclient to mock. Instead I have  a simple counter increasing logic that I want to test. I might also want to test pure presentation logic like changing the format of some text. So that's why you normally want to unit test the view model layer.

Regarding your suggestion that a swiftUI view is already playing the role of view model I don't buy this idea since one of the purpose of the view model is to create a logic layer independent of the UI framework ( like SwiftUI) with the benefit of being reusable in different UI systems.

Comment: You should probably stick to UIKit then because SwiftUI has already implemented that. Also formatting is automatic based on users region settings, not many developers bother to do that in UIKit because it's tricky to get right

Comment: I'm not following you. the presentation logic is certainly not restricted to  locale/region based formatting or data binding( the examples you made). Could be validation of a particular text field condition, or the fact that all the required field of a form are filled before to enable a "continue"  button. But it could also be the logic related to a specific animation occurring in a view, in some cases the logic required for accessibility etc. In all such cases you want to be able to test some aspects of those logic

Comment: Of course you can test logic, but you shouldn't use Combine's ObservableObject just for that. @Published is for assigning the end of a Combine pipeline. Instead, you'll need to learn structs and value semantics, eg mutating func in a custom state struct.

Comment: Can you just provide an example? how would you test that the behaviour of a presentation logic method of a view is correct? let's say MyView2 has a method called buttonEnabledOnFieldsFilled() that enables a button when all the fields of the view are filled. Normally you'd achieve it using a spy/mock version of the presentation layer object

Comment: Sure I added one

Comment: that's production code, it is not a test. My original question is clear but I explain it again in more details:  I need a test  to verify the correctness of the results in different scenarios with some different test strings and for that you need to use a mock/spy object so that you can control the input strings and check the result.
And by the way you are using what I'would call a viewModel just with the Content name.

Comment: Ok thought it was obvious but I added a test

Comment: yes, in this simple scenario using a mutable struct can be a viable option and I would still call the structure a ViewModel that allows the presentation logic layer to be separated from the UI layer, but in real life scenarios the view needs to use different dependencies services/managers like apiClient etc. Where would you put all these dependencies? and how would you make the view aware of the data coming from those dependencies?

Comment: Second observation: Using State rather than ObservableObject, again, is a viable option for the simplest cases like this one but normally you have many separated @State objects and using a ObservableObject allows you to encapsulate all in a separated class making the mechanism more scalable

Comment: That goes against Apple's guidance that the View structs should be the primary encapsulation mechanism for view data - not separate objects. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10040/?time=1251

Comment: Structs can be the easiest(primary in this sense maybe) mechanism for view state but for more complex scenarios we can definitely use observable objects. I don't think apple has made them available by mistake. Actually seeing  wwdc23 seems like they are pushing towards the new @observable objects(yes class instances). Anyway you didn't answer my question regarding where you'd put dependencies and the data produced by them available to the view

Comment: Services/managers go in an `EnvironmentKey` the data produced should go in `@State` and can be passed to child View structs via computed properties especially if they depend on other state, e.g. for filtering/sorting.

Comment: unfortunately Services/managers class instances and can't go in the Environment that only accepts value types.

Comment: The value can be a struct that can have objects  in a properties

Comment: FYI managedObjectContext is a class instance in the environment